# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm getting the error when the page is loaded. I'm trying to append a new object to an array of entries. What's wrong with this?

[image]

**raffle.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller("RaffleCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.entries = [
      {
        name: "Larry"
      }, {
        name: "Curly"
      }, {
        name: "Moe"
      }
    ]

  $scope.addEntry = function () {
    $scope.entries.push($scope.newEntry)
    $scope.newEntry = {}
  };

});
```

**index.html**

```
<h1>Raffler</h1>

<div ng-controller="RaffleCtrl">

  <form ng-sumbit="addEntry">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newEntry.name">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
  </form>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">{{entry.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you doing that javascript in a dom ready block?

Comment: @MaxWilliams No, I'm not doing it in ready() block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to define $scope.newEntry = {} outside
And parenthesis in form ng-sumbit="submit()"
Modify your code to..

$scope.entries = [
        {
          name: "Larry"
        }, {
          name: "Curly"
        }, {
          name: "Moe"
        }
      ];

```
  $scope.newEntry = {}  
   $scope.submit = function() {
     $scope.entries.push($scope.newEntry)
     $scope.newEntry = {}
   };
```

Comment: have a look at the url https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit
This is exactly what u r doing.